# Does return table defined inside a stored procedure creates a temporary table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

There is a stored procedure defined, which takes some parameters,it runs a loop inside it. The issue is that whenever I am executing this query, this single process/function takes 100% CPU usage and approx 2 mins to get executed,I have increased the number of cores but it still takes 100% CPU usage. I am thinking that maybe it is creating temporary tables and Postgresql is unable to autovaccum.

I have tried several configurations, but to no avail.

```
create
or replace
function some_function(offers numeric[],
list character varying[],
startdate date,
enddate date) returns table
  (prod character varying,
  offer numeric,
  dates date,
  baseline double precision,
  promoincremental double precision,
  couponincremental double precision,
  affinityquantity double precision,
  affinitymargin double precision,
  affinityrevenue double precision,
  cannibalisationquantity double precision,
  cannibalisationrevenue double precision,
  cannibalisationmargin double precision
    ) language plpgsql as $function$ declare a numeric[] := offers;

i numeric;
begin
foreach i in array a loop return QUERY select
  models.prod,
  i as offer,
  date(models.transdate_dt) as dates,
  greatest(0,(sum(models.unitretailprice) * sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price)) + (sum(models.flag::int) * sum(coefficients.flag::int)) + (sum(models.mc_baseline) * sum(coefficients.mc_baseline)) + (sum(models.mc_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_day_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_normal)) + (sum(models.mc_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_week_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_day_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_month_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_month_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal))) as baseline,
  greatest(0, ((0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a)))) as promoIncremental,
  greatest(0, (sum(models.basket_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.basket_per_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_per_off)) + (sum(models.category_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.category_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.category_per_off) * sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) + (sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per))) as couponIncremnetal,
  greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a))) * sum(affinity.pull) * sum(affinity.confidence) as affinityquantity,
  greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a))) * sum(affinity.margin_lift) * sum(affinity.confidence) as affinitymargin,
  greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a))) * sum(affinity.revenue_lift) * sum(affinity.confidence) as affinityrevenue,
  greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a)))/(NULLIF( greatest(0,(sum(models.unitretailprice) * sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price)) + (sum(models.flag::int) * sum(coefficients.flag::int)) + (sum(models.mc_baseline) * sum(coefficients.mc_baseline)) + (sum(models.mc_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_day_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_normal)) + (sum(models.mc_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_week_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_day_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_month_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_month_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal))) + greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a))) + greatest(0, (sum(models.basket_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.basket_per_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_per_off)) + (sum(models.category_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.category_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.category_per_off) * sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) + (sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per))), 0)) * sum(cannibalisation.effect) * (sum(products.price) - (sum(products.price) - i )) as cannibalisationquantity,
  ((sum(products.price) - i) * sum(models.disc_per) - (sum(products.price) - i) ) * (   greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a)))/(NULLIF( greatest(0,(sum(models.unitretailprice) * sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price)) + (sum(models.flag::int) * sum(coefficients.flag::int)) + (sum(models.mc_baseline) * sum(coefficients.mc_baseline)) + (sum(models.mc_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_day_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_normal)) + (sum(models.mc_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_week_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_day_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_month_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_month_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal))) + greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a))) + greatest(0, (sum(models.basket_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.basket_per_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_per_off)) + (sum(models.category_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.category_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.category_per_off) * sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) + (sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per))), 0)) * sum(cannibalisation.effect) * (sum(products.price) -  (sum(products.price) - i ) )) as cannibalisationrevenue,
  (((sum(products.price) - i) * sum(models.disc_per) - (sum(products.price) - i) ) - sum(products.cost)) * (    greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a)))/(NULLIF(greatest(0,(sum(models.unitretailprice) * sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price)) + (sum(models.flag::int) * sum(coefficients.flag::int)) + (sum(models.mc_baseline) * sum(coefficients.mc_baseline)) + (sum(models.mc_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_day_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_normal)) + (sum(models.mc_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_avg)) + (sum(models.mc_week_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_day_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_month_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_month_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_month_normal)) + (sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) + (sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal))) + greatest(0, (0 * sum(coefficients.f)) + (0 * sum(coefficients.p)) + (i * sum(coefficients.a))) + greatest(0, (sum(models.basket_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.basket_per_off) * sum(coefficients.basket_per_off)) + (sum(models.category_dollar_off) * sum(coefficients.category_dollar_off)) + (sum(models.category_per_off) * sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) + (sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per))), 0)) * sum(cannibalisation.effect) * (sum(products.price) - (sum(products.price) - i )  )) as cannibalisationmargin 
from
  models
join coefficients on
  models.prod = coefficients.prod
  and models.si_type = coefficients.si_type
  and models.model_type = coefficients.model_type
left join products on
  products.unique_id1 = models.prod
left join affinity on
  affinity.prod = models.prod
left join cannibalisation on
  cannibalisation.prod = models.prod
where
  coefficients.prod = any(skusList)
  and models.transdate_dt >= startDate
  and models.transdate_dt <= endDate
group by
  models.prod,
  dates,
  offer ;
end loop;
end;
$function$ ;
```

Here I call the function with these parameters:::::

```
select
  *
from
  some_function(array[1.5,
  2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5 ],
  '{12841276, 11873916,07915473, 01504273,10405843,11231446,12224242,11249380,08604365, 11248952, 11230018,10447621,11229820,10406916,09578733,11280161, 01503697, 11923554, 10406460,11295219,01458421,09053893,11224409, 06755789, 11317377, 11275047,12231817,11309507,10447522,10406296, 10406338, 01460658, 12272811,11318870,11248838,10406130,11248812, 11223682, 11276748, 10447605, 11232451, 10405827,10447670,08177743, 10405231, 02326791, 12224226,12231650,11929197,01504380 }',
  '2018-01-02'::date,
  '2018-01-06'::date );
```

I expected it to take around 30% CPU usage at a max because it is performing some calculations but it is taking down 100% CPU usage, Can anyone kindly help in this regard?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe RETURN QUERY wont return from the function , infact it appends the results to the final result rows. A  RETURN at the end of function will return from the function

Comment: You want to remove the loop and push down the array inside the query instead. The function would then execute one query instead of N.

Comment: Also surely you don't want to keep these multiplications by zero as in `0 * sum(coefficients.f)`

Comment: @DanielVérité thanks for the reply, but I dont want to remove the loop because instead of hitting the database 19 times one by one, I think it will be to run a loop instead.

Comment: @RohanKumar He's not saying that you should call the function 19 times, he's saying that you should remove the loop from the function and instead join on the unnested array.  Loops are rarely a good idea in functions like this.

Comment: @DanielVérité can you update your answer with some query like for example rewrite my query with your recommendations.

Comment: @Jeremy can you update your answer with some query like for example rewrite my query with your recommendations